# InvalidArgumentError when training model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on an RNN with LSTMs that's supposed to generate handwriting and I have been trying to train the model for weeks now. The model actually works but the results are mediocre because the training always stops quite early.

The training always throws this exception:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Found Inf or NaN global norm.`

My partners and my first guess was that we have an exploding gradient problem on our hand. So what we've tried so far:

- Reducing Batch-Size
- Switching from Adam Optimizer to RMSprop
- Reducing Data-Scaling
- Reducing Learning Rate extremely (Actually finishes training)
- Reducing and Increasing gradient clipping

With only one of those methods preventing the error but with the drawback that the model still had a high normal loss and didn't perform well.

The error happens here

```py
grads = tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars)

grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, params.grad_clip) #tf.gradients(ys, xs) calculates the gradient of ys w.r.t 

self.train_op = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars)) # training operation (learning)
```

And these are our parameters:

```py
self.batch_size=32 if self.train else 1 #only for training
self.tsteps=200 if self.train else 1 #only for backprob in LSTM cell(time steps to complete the sentence)
self.data_scale = 100 #amount to scale data down before training
self.limit = 500
self.tsteps_per_ascii=25 #estimation for one char at gaussian conv./char window
self.alphabet=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
self.data_dir="./data/"
self.len_threshold=1
#mode
self.rnn_size = 100
self.dropout = 0.85 #probability of keeping neuron during dropout; architecture learns more general
self.kmixtures = 1 #number of gaussian mixtures for character window
self.nmixtures = 8 #number of gaussian mixtures 
self.learning_rate = 0.00001 #learing rat
self.grad_clip = 10. # clip gradients to this magnitude (avoid exploding gradiend
self.optimizer = 'rms' # adam or rm
self.lr_decay = 1.0
self.decay = 0.95
self.momentum = 0.9
```

Comment: Is there a reason for why you don't use LSTM? By reading the error message it self, my first though is that dataset contains a invalid number (Inf or Nan). I assume that you have created a check for that?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I didn't mention it but we actually use LSTM. We are using the IAM Handwriting Database to train the model so we assumed it doesn't have any problems.

Comment: I see. Take a look at this link, which had the same problem as you: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6178

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve our issue. We actually found something quite interesting through your suggestion but ultimately the training didn't crash but it resulted in a stagnating learning process with value loss staying quite high.